# Prove that $H^{2}(S^{2})\neq 0$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

**Prove that $H^{2}(S^{2})\neq 0$**

Suppose $\omega$ is an area form of $S^{2}$. An arbitrary two form on $S^{2}$ is closed as if $f(x,y)dx\wedge dy\in\Omega^{2}(S^{2})$ then $d(f(x,y)dx\wedge dy)=0$. I claim that $[\omega]\neq 0$ i.e $\omega$ is not exact. (then $\omega$ is not homologous to $0$).

Suppose by contradiction that $[\omega]=0$ i.e $\omega$ is exact, which means that$\;\exists\;\alpha\in\Omega^{1}(S^{2})$ such that $\omega=d\alpha$. Stoke's theorem gives now

$\text{Area}(S^{2})=\displaystyle\int_{S^{2}}\omega=\int_{S^{2}}d\alpha=\int_{\partial S^{2}}\alpha=0$ as $\;\partial S^{2}=\emptyset\;$, a contradiction.

Is it correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. The same argument shows that for a compact orientable smooth manifold $M$ (without boundary) of dimension $n$, $H^n_{\text{dR}}(M) \neq 0$. As $M$ is orientable, there is a nowhere zero $n$-form $\omega$. As $M$ is $n$-dimensional, $d\omega = 0$, so $[\omega] \in H^n_{\text{dR}}(M)$. By the same argument as in your answer, $\omega$ cannot be closed, so $[\omega] \neq 0$. Therefore, $H^n_{\text{dR}}(M) \neq 0$. In fact, $H^n_{\text{dR}}(M) = \mathbb{R}$ but this requires a bit more work.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Could you help me out with one example more?  $H^{i}(\mathbb{R}^{2}),\;\;i=1,2$?

 For $i=0$ we have $H^{0}(\mathbb{R}^{2})=\mathbb{R}$ as $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is connected and has only 1 component.  
But how to show that for $i=1$ $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{2})=0$?

Comment: For any simply connected manifold $M$, $H^1_{\text{dR}}(M) = 0$.

Comment: so for a connected $M$, $H^{0}(M)=0$, (e.q $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus(0,0)$, for simply connected $M$, $H^{1}(M)=0$ (e.q $\mathbb{R}^{2})$.

 How can we prove that $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{2})=0$,  using just the definition?

Comment: No, if $M$ is connected, $H^0_{\text{dR}}(M) = \mathbb{R}$. As for $H^1_{\text{dR}}(\mathbb{R}^2) = 0$, you may want to consider the Poincaré Lemma. I don't know what you're trying to say about $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0, 0)\}$ as $H^1_{\text{dR}}(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}) = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Right, it was a typo. With $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus (0,0)$ I meant that the space is connected but not simply connected, hence $H^{0}(\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus (0,0))=\mathbb{R}$ also $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus (0,0))=\mathbb{R}$.
But $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is simply connected hence $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^2)=0$. Can we prove it rigorously ( the formulation of the problem requires that this is proved by defintion)....?

Comment: Following your suggestion: $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is ( an open star shaped domain w.r.to $0$) then every closed form on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is exact. Let $1$-form $\omega=f(x,y)dx+f(x,y)dy$ be arbitrary on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, $\omega$ is closed and exact by the lemma, so $[\omega]=0$ in $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$,so$H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{2})=0$. Thank you Michael for guiding me through this problem.